# Django signup doesn't save extra fields in db

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-registration

I'm trying to add some extra fields for user registration in my django app.User can signup successfully but extra fields like first_name, last_name and email doesn't save in db.

help me, please!

Here's my forms.py:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Here's views.py:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
form_class = UserCreationForm
template_name = 'users/signup.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it'll help you: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html